# How to update a belongs_to model after calling clear on has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have two ActiveRecord Models (I'm not going to include migrations):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscription, :inverse_of => :users
end
```

and

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :inverse_of => :subscription
end
```

In `rails console` I can create a new object for each model, then add a user to the subscription model:

```
>> s = Subscription.create
  => #<Subscription id: 1>
>> u = User.create
  => #<User id: 1, subscription_id: nil>
>> s.users << u
  => [#<User id: 1, subscription_id: 1>]
>> u
  => #<User id: 1, subscription_id: 1>
```

But if I use the Array.clear method, it clears out the collection, but doesn't immediately update the associated model:

```
>> s.users.clear
  => []
>> u
  => #<User id: 1, subscription_id: 1>
```

If I call `u.reload` it will pull the most recent version from the database, but it shouldn't have to do that in order to update my cached model. I tried using `:inverse_of` as suggested in [Bi-Directional Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations), but it didn't work.

Comment: why is the inverse_of different syntax from each other?

Comment: I updated the link. The `inverse_of` arguments are different because the specify the opposite class in the bi-directional relationship. If I want to see what users have a subscription, I invoke `s.users`. This is why in the User model, the `inverse_of` is `users`. The opposite applies to the Subscription model.

Comment: shouldn't it both be ":inverse_of =>" your subscription model is missing the "=>" not sure if it helps but that's what I was asking about

Comment: You're right. I mistyped it in the question, but it's correct now. My source code didn't have this typo, though.